# button click save sharedPreferences

Tags: android, kotlin, main-activity

I am trying to implement a save button that saves shared preferences from several editText inputs.

I am trying to implement a button function that when pressed saves the values from multiple editTexts, into sharedPreference keys.
After some research i have set what is in the editText fields as variables, which i will then write into shared preferences.

```
fun onClick() {

        var str = editText2.text.toString()
        var dex = editText.text.toString()
        var int = editText4.text.toString()

        when () {
            R.id.button -> {
                //add write sharedPreferences
            }
        }
}
```

I am getting an expecting an expression error when i try and compile it, in the when brackets.

Answer (score 3):

`when` needs an argument which will be compared to the cases like the case `R.id.button`.

So you can implement the onClickListener interface like

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        //setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar))

        button.setOnClikListener(this)

        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> true
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        var str = editText2.text.toString()
        var dex = editText.text.toString()
        var int = editText4.text.toString()

        when (v.id) {
            R.id.button -> {
                //add write sharedPreferences
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: button.setOnClickListener(this) ?. I changed it to what you suggested and am getting 5 'expecting member declaration' errors on the public void line.

Comment: ok so my `onCreate()` method is just a short version of the android lifecycle `onCreate()`. I will edit it so it looks properly

Comment: Ah i see, Thank you. I changed it to that version you edited, and i can understand it, however still results in 7 'expecting member declaration' errors on the 'protected void' line.

Comment: my bad, we are talking in Kotlin but I wrote OnCreate in java. See current edit if it works

Comment: Ah, lol, woops. I just changed it, and results in the following errors, https://imagebin.ca/v/4hjXkdsQnKvk , so maybe there is something bigger wrong, my complete code in on github.com/brobostigon/TW01 .

Comment: yes :) please dont copy paste the provided solution, but apply it to your needs :) I will copy here how your main activity should look like

Comment: My MainActivity.kt looks like as you stated, and got the following results, https://imagebin.ca/v/4hjrUDzdHNhX

Comment: Could a way of doing this be, making the TextViews next to the editText fields, clickable, then creating functions to save whats in those editText fields, setting android:onClick on those TextViews, to call those save functions?